# Reading a file in R

Tags: r, read.table

I would like to read a file in R as a table for a file that contains information in an odd format.

The file data.txt has the data written as:

```
04001400 HI 34.50 118.27 19480701 08 LST
         0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
       MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS
04001400 HI 34.50 118.27 19480801 08 LST
         0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
       MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS
04001400 HI 34.50 118.27 19480901 08 LST
         0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
       MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS
```

the first number is a station number, HI is a case, the third and fourth numbers are lat and long coordinates, the other number is year,month,day,, and the other number (08) is time zone, followed by LST meaning time frame.  The following 24 numbers or in the above example the 0's and MIS are values for a particular region and time.  I am trying to store the contents of the file as a table in this type of format of dimension [n x 31] (where 31 is the number of columns and n is the amount of rows total in the file):

```
04001400 HI 34.50 118.27 19480701 08 LST 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS

04001400 HI 34.50 118.27 19480801 08 LST 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS

04001400 HI 34.50 118.27 19480901 08 LST 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS
```

I have tried coding it this way based on the function read.table:

```
data <- read.table("data.txt", sep = c("\b", "\t", "\n"))
```

But it does not work as I have described above.  Is there a way that I can do that?  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `scan` to read multi-line data, especially since it is a specific format.

```
dat <- data.frame(scan("data.txt",
what = as.list(c("character","character","number","number",
                 "character","number","character",
                  rep("character",24))),
multi.line=TRUE))
names(dat) <- paste("V",1:ncol(dat),sep="")
```

which gives

```
> dat
        V1 V2    V3     V4       V5 V6  V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16
1 04001400 HI 34.50 118.27 19480701 08 LST  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2 04001400 HI 34.50 118.27 19480801 08 LST  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3 04001400 HI 34.50 118.27 19480901 08 LST  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
  V17 V18 V19 V20 V21 V22 V23 V24 V25 V26 V27 V28 V29 V30 V31
1   0   0   0 MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS
2   0   0   0 MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS
3   0   0   0 MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS MIS
> dim(dat)
[1]  3 31
```

You could, of course, give more informative names to the columns.

EDIT:

As Josh points out in the comments, my `what` argument was of the wrong format and caused all columns to be imported as character rather than some as character and some as numeric.  It should have read:

```
dat <- data.frame(scan("data.txt",
what = list(character(), character(), numeric(), numeric(),
            character(), numeric(), character(),
            character(), character(), character(), character(),
            character(), character(), character(), character(),
            character(), character(), character(), character(),
            character(), character(), character(), character(),
            character(), character(), character(), character(),
            character(), character(), character(), character()),
multi.line=TRUE))
names(dat) <- paste("V",1:ncol(dat),sep="")
```

which gives the more appropriate:

```
> str(dat)

'data.frame':   3 obs. of  31 variables:
 $ V1 : Factor w/ 1 level "04001400": 1 1 1
 $ V2 : Factor w/ 1 level "HI": 1 1 1
 $ V3 : num  34.5 34.5 34.5
 $ V4 : num  118 118 118
 $ V5 : Factor w/ 3 levels "19480701","19480801",..: 1 2 3
 $ V6 : num  8 8 8
 $ V7 : Factor w/ 1 level "LST": 1 1 1
 $ V8 : Factor w/ 1 level "0": 1 1 1
 $ V9 : Factor w/ 1 level "0": 1 1 1
 $ V10: Factor w/ 1 level "0": 1 1 1
 $ V11: Factor w/ 1 level "0": 1 1 1
 $ V12: Factor w/ 1 level "0": 1 1 1
 $ V13: Factor w/ 1 level "0": 1 1 1
 $ V14: Factor w/ 1 level "0": 1 1 1
 $ V15: Factor w/ 1 level "0": 1 1 1
 $ V16: Factor w/ 1 level "0": 1 1 1
 $ V17: Factor w/ 1 level "0": 1 1 1
 $ V18: Factor w/ 1 level "0": 1 1 1
 $ V19: Factor w/ 1 level "0": 1 1 1
 $ V20: Factor w/ 1 level "MIS": 1 1 1
 $ V21: Factor w/ 1 level "MIS": 1 1 1
 $ V22: Factor w/ 1 level "MIS": 1 1 1
 $ V23: Factor w/ 1 level "MIS": 1 1 1
 $ V24: Factor w/ 1 level "MIS": 1 1 1
 $ V25: Factor w/ 1 level "MIS": 1 1 1
 $ V26: Factor w/ 1 level "MIS": 1 1 1
 $ V27: Factor w/ 1 level "MIS": 1 1 1
 $ V28: Factor w/ 1 level "MIS": 1 1 1
 $ V29: Factor w/ 1 level "MIS": 1 1 1
 $ V30: Factor w/ 1 level "MIS": 1 1 1
 $ V31: Factor w/ 1 level "MIS": 1 1 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, works great!  And of course I took care of the names of the columns, just reading it was the hard part.

Comment: Hi Brian. The `what` argument you've provided reads in all of the columns as character vectors -- probably not what you intended. To see why, compare the results of these three bits of code: `scan(textConnection("A 1 B 2"), what=list("character", "number"))`; `scan(textConnection("A 1 B 2"), what=list(character(), numeric()))`; and `scan(textConnection("A 1 B 2"), what=list("UggaBugga", 111))`.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien:

What you have suggested may be a reason why I can't get a listing of unique ID for V1 as stated by Brain with a simple call to unique(dat[1,])?  Also, what way would you suggest to alter Brian's code to include numeric values, not all character?

Comment: @LucianoRodriguez That's a separate problem. You should try instead `unique(dat[ , 1]` (which I now see you did). To read in some columns in as numeric, just replace any instances of `"number"` in Brian's code with `numeric()` (with no quotes around it).

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Unfortunately by substituting numeric() for all "number" doesn't create the same format as before.  Plus I was given a warning "Warning message:
In scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  :
  number of items read is not a multiple of the number of columns"

Any suggestions?

Comment: Two thoughts. If Brian's solution was otherwise working, it's OK to read all of the columns in as character columns, and convert particular columns using, e.g. `dat$V3 <- as.numeric(dat$V3)`. If his code was giving you the same error, it may be an indication that some of your lines of data were missing one or more items of data. I'd suggest trying the code out on just the first few records of your data file, and if those work, building up from there. (If you try that, you might want to have a look at the `nmax` argument to scan, which controls the number of records to be read in).

Comment: I found the dilemma with my code.  As it turns out, unfortunately, the data purchased from USGS has an extra hour (25 points as oppose to 24 points) or sometimes one less hour since it is meshed with another hour.  Therefore, I must carefully run a code to look where within the file there is an inconsistency.  Nevertheless, I thank you for your help and patience.

Comment: I'm guessing that the extra or missing hour is Daylight Savings Time related, where one day a year has 25 hours and one day has 23.

Comment: I was consulting with a professor of mine who worked with this type of data years ago and the extra point is total daily rainfall, which should be deleted.  Therefore, while scanning, I must detect whether there is an extra point so I can ignore it by skipping it and moving on to the next value.  The only way I think of overcoming this is reading character by character as oppose to using the scan function.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is

```
a <- read.table("sample.txt", fill=T);
aseq <- seq(1, dim(a)[1], by=3)
x <- data.frame(a[aseq, 1:7], a[aseq+1,], a[aseq+2,])
```

The 1:7 is needed because read.table() created NA columns.